# Missing VolumeGUIDs in Windows 2016 MountedDevices registry key

Tags: linux, windows

Our software runs on Linux and we need to create a mapping between Linux device name(something like /dev/sda1) and VolumeGUID as it appears in Windows, since we are examining Windows disks/partitions.

We get this information from MountedDevices Windows Registry subkey.

Problem occurs on Windows 2016, where Volume{GUID}s are no longer listed in MountedDevices subkey.

I managed to figure out, that Volume{GUID} is not a random GUID anymore(which is probably why they do not have to be stored it registry anymore), but it gets composed from data in the partition table.

In case of GPT, the VolumeGUID is actually a GPT partition GUID, which is great, because I can easily reconstruct those VolumeGUIDs.

In case of MBR, it is something like:

\?\Volume{46e21ed5-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\

\?\Volume{46e21ed5-0000-0000-0000-104000000000}\

\?\Volume{46e21ed5-0000-0000-0000-108000000000}\

\?\Volume{46e21ed5-0000-0000-0000-20c000000000}\

...

Where 46e21ed5 is actually a disk signature, but I'm not sure what other fields mean. It looks like there's a partition offset (0x400 = 1024, and each partition is 1024MB in the provided example), but something does not add up for the last partition which has 20C00.

Does anyone have more information on this subject and how these volume GUIDs get composed? (Google does not find any information on this subject)

Regards

Comment: This is a implementation detail. Are you reading registry files while Windows is not actually booted or is it acceptable to call a documented Windows function while Windows is running?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? From what I can see you never got to the problem. This question merely explained that your proposed solution to an undisclosed problem isn't.